# How to locate installed module inside visual studio code

Tags: python, error-handling, module

So i have installed the pandas module, and wanting to execute it has not ne easy as well as some other modules, because i keep getting the NoModuleError. Also pylance keeps reperting the missing module source and missing module. Please how do i rectify this issue and find the missing modules. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Python find modules in paths specified in **sys.path**.
Check the path where pandas is installed in **sys.path**
import sys
print(sys.path)

If that does not exist in **sys.path** then you can append the the path where
pandas is installed like
sys.path.append('path to folder where pandas is installed')